# compare function and parameter in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing functions in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328620/comparing-functions-in-haskell)

I'm learning haskell, wanted to know is something like this possible? 
All I want is to compare if parameter 'function' is equal to one of the functions a or b. How to do this?

Example code:

```
a,b :: Integer -> Integer
a x = x+1
b x = x-1

c function parameter = if function == a 
           then ... parameter -- Do a related stuff
           else ... parameter -- Do b related stuff
```

Comment: I'm no Haskell expert, but in order to use the function `(==)` the parameters have to be part of the `Eq` typeclass, and I don't think functions can be part of typeclasses.

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4328965/195701): _`There is not, and will never be, a way to compare two functions for equality. There is a mathematical proof that it is not possible in general.`_

Comment: @VincentSavard:
    instance Num b => Num (a -> b) where
       (f + g) x = f x + g x
           -- ...

Comment: @Fixnum: Interesting! I'm not quite familiar with the syntax (I can only write really basic programs), but there's a lot of concepts I'll have to look into!

Answer (score 2):

The only case I know of where you can compare two functions for equality is if their domain has a finite number of values.  For example, if you have two functions of type:

```
f, g :: Bool -> A
```

Then they are equal if they are equal for all inputs:

```
f == g = (f False == g False) && (f True == g True)
```

However, for the case of `Int`, comparing them on every possible value of `Int` is impractical and inefficient.  For `Integer`, it can't be done since `Integer`s are unbounded.

As @Miguel correctly pointed out in his comment, functions with non-finite domains cannot be compared for equality in general.